# Обработчик нажатия

Tags: android, android-menu

У меня есть меню с пунктами, но при нажатии ничего не происходит. Вот пример кода:

```
menu.add("Настройки")
                .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
                        return true;
}
```

Какой код тут добавить, чтобы при нажатии на пункт меню, открылась новое `Activity` с настройками?

Comment: Ну... Вызвать `finish();` сразу перед `return true;`?

Comment: Можете добавить перед `return true;` строчку `onMenuItemClick(item);`. Какое либо событие произойдет.

Comment: Код открытия нового активити с настройками

Comment: Знаю что этот код. Но как он пишется полностью?

Comment: @akmaltilloev для вызова Activity добавьте startActivity(new Intent(ActivityVizova.this, ActivityKotroeVizivaem.class)); еще надо определить какой пункт меню вызван, смотрите как в ответе с WebView

Comment: Ответ подошёл. Добавьте в ответы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kод для вызова `Activity` при нажатии на пункта меню.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemid()) {
case R.id.action_settings:
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
return true;
case R.id.action_about:
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutActivity.class));
return true;
default:
return super.onOptionItemSelected(item);
```

Спасибо Lex Hobbit