# При долгом нажатии на элемент не выводится меню "Копировать"

Tags: android

Я создал программу, которая содержит различные тексты, но когда на них нажимаю и удерживаю, не выводится системное меню "Копировать".

Как создать такое меню?
Желательно с полным кодом и объяснением.

Comment: в каких элементах текст отображаете?

Comment: У меня текст выводиться на WebView.

Comment: тогда не сработает метод в ответе

Comment: обновил ответ, это если  хотите именно WebView

Comment: Кажется первый ответ который вы дали, точно работает)

Comment: Можете помочь с этим https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/700966

Comment: А с этим? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/700409/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте к элементу, в котором расположен текст, атрибут `android:textIsSelectable="true"`. Этот метод не будет работать для WebView, так как у него нет такого атрибута.

## Как добавить в WebView возможность копирования?

Создадим разметку для меню `res/menu/menu.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/copy"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_copy"
    android:showAsAction="always" 
    android:title="copy">
</item>
```

Необходимо будет создать собственный класс унаследованный от `WebView`, который переопределит `ActionBar` при долгом нажатии на текст в `WebView`.

```
public class CustomWebView extends WebView {
    private Context context;

    public CustomWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        WebSettings webviewSettings = getSettings();
        webviewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        // добавляем JavaScript интерфейс для копирования
        addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(context), "JSInterface");
    }

    private ActionMode mActionMode;
    private ActionMode.Callback mSelectActionModeCallback;
    private GestureDetector mDetector;

    // переопределит ActionBar при долгом нажатии на текст WebView
    @Override
    public ActionMode startActionMode(Callback callback) {
        ViewParent parent = getParent();
        if (parent == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            String name = callback.getClass().toString();
            if (name.contains("SelectActionModeCallback")) {
                mSelectActionModeCallback = callback;
                mDetector = new GestureDetector(context,
                        new CustomGestureListener());
            }
        }
        CustomActionModeCallback mActionModeCallback = new CustomActionModeCallback();
        return parent.startActionModeForChild(this, mActionModeCallback);
    }

    private class CustomActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mActionMode = mode;
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.copy:
                    getSelectedData();
                    mode.finish();
                    return true;
                default:
                    mode.finish();
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                clearFocus();
            } else {
                if (mSelectActionModeCallback != null) {
                    mSelectActionModeCallback.onDestroyActionMode(mode);
                }
                mActionMode = null;
            }
        }
    }

    // функция получения выделенного текста на JS
    private void getSelectedData() {
        // определяем JS функцию для выделения
        String js = "(function getSelectedText() {" +
                "var txt;" +
                "if (window.getSelection) {" +
                "txt = window.getSelection().toString();" +
                "} else if (window.document.getSelection) {" +
                "txt = window.document.getSelection().toString();" +
                "} else if (window.document.selection) {" +
                "txt = window.document.selection.createRange().text;" +
                "}" +
                "JSInterface.getText(txt);" +
                "})()";
        // вызываем JS функцию для выделения
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            evaluateJavascript("javascript:" + js, null);
        } else {
            loadUrl("javascript:" + js);
        }
    }

    private class CustomGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            if (mActionMode != null) {
                mActionMode.finish();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (mDetector != null)
            mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Создадим слушателя в отдельном интерфейсе, который отработает, когда выполнится JS функция копирования.

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void getText(String text) {
        // помещаем выделенный текст в ClipData
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)
                mContext.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("simple text", text);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
        // покажем что скопировали
        Toast.makeText(mContext, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Первый код в первом активити и второй на активити в котором есть webview?

Comment: @akmaltilloev просто все свои WebView можете смело менять на CustomWebView

Comment: Заранее извиняюсь за глупый вопрос. А как это сделать?

Comment: @akmaltilloev ctrl+R в Android Studio в файлах, где есть WebView

Comment: Когда добавил код на MainActivity, WebAppOnterface подчеркнуть красным! Что делать?

Comment: @akmaltilloev а что пишет?

Comment: Потом добавил слушателя и все ошибка пропала. Но когда собрал приложение, оно как говорится вообще перестал работат. Сначала когда нажимал на список выводился текст. После написание этого кода, когда нажимал на списка приложение вылетела.